# How to reset a laptop BIOS with no CMOS battery?

Tags: laptop, bios, asus-laptop, cmos

I have an **Asus X455LD** and I tried to update its BIOS and it went wrong.  The laptop turned off when the process finished, and now when I press power button it does not turn on. The power led turns on, but nothing else. Can I reset the BIOS? **It seems to have no a CMOS battery**.

Comment: https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1012219/

Comment: The problem is that the laptop actually wont't turn on. The screen stays black. Only power led turns on

Comment: Try it anyway. Create a usb disk, insert it and turn on. It should be detected and the screen should turn on.

Comment: Thank you guys, it's working now. I tried this method before, but I don't know why the laptop didn't detect the USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this page](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1012219/), create recovery usb and insert it, then power up, it should recover the bios automatically.

> The `ASUS CrashFree BIOS 3` utility is an auto recovery tool that
>   allows you to restore the BIOS file when it fails or gets corrupted
>   during the updating process. You can restore a corrupted BIOS file by
>   using the motherboard-support CD or a USB flash drive that contains
>   the latest/original BIOS file.
>
> 1. Turn on the system.
> 2. Insert the motherboard-support CD to the optical drive, or the USB flash drive which contains the BIOS file to the USB port.
> 3. The utility automatically checks whether the BIOS file is saved in the device. When the BIOS file is found, the utility starts to read
>      the BIOS file and automatically enters `ASUS EZ Flash 3`.
> 4. The system requires you to enter the BIOS Setup to recover the BIOS settings. To ensure the system compatibility and stability, we
>      recommend that you press  to load the default BIOS values.
>
> Note: DO NOT shut down or reset the system while updating the BIOS!
>   Doing so can cause system boot failure!
>
> - `CrashFree BIOS 3` program is built into the BIOS, you don't need to install the additional programs.
> - Availability of `CrashFree BIOS 3` program depends on whether the motherboard specifications are supported.